# Not able to retrieve attributes from the Expand

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-webapi

I am trying to fetch attributes of Email with `email_active_mime_attachments` with `filename` and `filesize` from the **expand**. I am able to get only attributes of Email but not selected values from **expand**. Please help on this, not sure where I am missing those values

> /api/data/v8.2/emails?$select=createdon,directioncode,senton,statecode,subject&$expand=email_activity_mime_attachment($select=activitymimeattachmentid,filename,filesize,_ownerid_value)

I am trying to read value of that `filename` into a variable, but seems the way I used not working.

Please provide your valuable suggestions on this.

Answer (score 1):

Expand will give you that related information only when you retrieve single record. If you want to get related information I would suggest to compose fetchxml and retrieve data through it.

Comment: Thank you, Andrii. I will try out that.